# Unexpected End of File in FORTRAN?

Tags: file, fortran, unexpectendoffile

I've been looking on the net but I haven't found any solution yet.

I'm trying to read from a .neu (neutral format) file, which is a type of file generated by the Gambit software, and contains information about a mesh used in CFD calculations.

The file goes like this:

```
        CONTROL INFO 2.4.6
** GAMBIT NEUTRAL FILE
S1
PROGRAM:                Gambit     VERSION:  2.4.6

     NUMNP     NELEM     NGRPS    NBSETS     NDFCD     NDFVL
    120847    240234         1         1         2         2
ENDOFSECTION
   NODAL COORDINATES 2.4.6
         1  0.00000000000e+000  2.50000000000e+001
         2  0.00000000000e+000  0.00000000000e+000
         3  0.00000000000e+000  2.49000000000e+001
         4  0.00000000000e+000  2.48000000000e+001
        ...
```

I'm trying to read the following line:

```
120847    240234         1         1         2         2
```

Here's my code:

```
PROGRAM readGAMBIT

    INTEGER, DIMENSION(6) :: mdata
    LOGICAL :: lexist
    INTEGER :: i

    INQUIRE (FILE="mesh.neu", EXIST=lexist)
    IF (.not.lexist) THEN
        STOP "**** mesh.neu does not exist ****"
    ENDIF

    OPEN(77,file="mesh.neu")

    DO i = 1, 6
        READ(1,*) ! Ignores the 1st 6 lines
    ENDDO

    READ(1,*) mdata(1), mdata(2), mdata(3), mdata(4), mdata(5), mdata(6)
    PRINT*, mdata(1)

    CLOSE(77)

END PROGRAM readGAMBIT
```

However, when I run this code I get "Fortran runtime error: End of file" . The file only ends after a couple thousand lines however.

What am I doing wrong? Why is the program thinking that the file only ends at the first line?

Answer (score 4):

Here's what my compiler says:

```
> nagfor -C=all -C=undefined readGAMBIT.f90 && ./a.out 
....
Runtime Error: End of file on unit 1
Program terminated by I/O error on unit 1 (File="fort.1",Formatted,Sequential)
Abort (core dumped)
```

It is pretty clear that you are associating `mesh.neu` to unit `77` but then attempting to read from unit `1`.

If your compiler supports the Fortran 2008 `NEWUNIT=` specifier on the `OPEN` statement then I suggest you use that, as follows (and prettified)

```
Program readgambit
  Integer, Dimension (6) :: mdata
  Logical :: lexist
  Integer :: i, newunit
  Inquire (File='mesh.neu', Exist=lexist)
  If (.Not. lexist) Then
    Stop '**** mesh.neu does not exist ****'
  End If
  Open (File='mesh.neu', Newunit=newunit)
  Do i = 1, 6
    Read (newunit, *) ! Ignores the 1st 6 lines
  End Do
  Read (newunit, *) mdata(1), mdata(2), mdata(3), mdata(4), mdata(5), mdata(6)
  Print *, mdata(1)
  Close (newunit)
End Program
```

which for me gives

```
> nagfor -C=all -C=undefined readGAMBIT.f90 && ./a.out
...
 120847
```

Comment: And even without `newunit=` support, he can do `newunit = 77` if necessary.